# zombie object that shouldn't be a zombie

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, release-management, nszombie

I have a navigation view iPhone app. I created a simple object that has a 'name' NSString and a 'weight' NSNumber. This app keeps crashing when loading a cell. Here is the method:

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

// Configure the cell...
factor *toAdd = [factors objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.textLabel.text = toAdd.name;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [toAdd.weight stringValue];
    // ^ crashes here...
    // stringByAppendingString:@"%"];

return cell;
}
```

I get the "message sent to deallocated instance" on the console when calling the stringValue method on the NSNumber. I don't understand why this is happening. The line above has no problem accessing the name and I have no [release] statements.

Thank you

EDIT:
Here's my factor's init method. I double checked and weight is (retain,nonatomic) and synthesized in implementation, just like name.

```
- (id) init{
if( self = [super init] )
{
    weight = [NSNumber numberWithInt:10];
    name = @"Homework";
}
return self;
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the comment `// stringByAppendingString:@"%"];` ?

Comment: are you feeding your method bath salt?

Comment: the weight is a percent value, so I want my string to have the '%' symbol at the end. I commented it out to fix the [NSNumber stringValue] problem first, then I'll uncomment.

Comment: try [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",to.Add], really though to make things easier i would use ARC if you can.

Comment: @owengerig Understanding memory management is important though, and while using ARC would 'fix' the problem, it does not a better programmer make.

Comment: ok i tried cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",toAdd.weight] and it gave me a number that I didn't expect. The value I expected was 10 and it showed 7thousand something...i'm guessing memory location. Then I tried cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[toAdd.weight stringValue] and I get the zombie error again. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the property setter method in your init. Thus the objects are not retained.

Try this:

```
- (id) init{
if( self = [super init] )
{
    self.weight = [NSNumber numberWithInt:10];
    self.name = @"Homework";
}
return self;
}
```

To avoid these kinds of errors you can synthesize properties with:

```
@synthesize name = _name;
```

Comment: the only thing is that it should be _weight not self. you shouldnt use accessors in init method.  unless im wrong?  certainly possible

Comment: using self worked. One question though, what is the difference between @ synthesize name and @ synthesize name = _name. What does giving a different name do?  thank you

Comment: this names the ivar _name instead of name and the compiler will throw an error if you try to set name with `name = @"Homework"`. Read this for a detailed explanation: http://weblog.bignerdranch.com/463-a-motivation-for-ivar-decorations/

Answer (score 0):

Being able to access the `name` property successfully has nothing to do with whether or not the `weight` property has been released yet. All that tells you is that your `factor` is alive and well, and that its `name` is also alive and well. I'm guessing you're not properly retaining your `weight` property in the implementation of `factor`.

EDIT: With the added code, that's *definitely* what you're doing.

Comment: I posted my factor init method, I don't have any release statements anywhere. Also, weight is a @property (retain,nonatomic) just like name.

Comment: @gamda, `[NSNumber numberWithInt:10]` returns an autoreleased object. You don't own it, and it will be released very quickly unless you retain it. If you have properties declared for those ivar, use `self.weight = [NSNumber numberWithInt:10]` instead

Comment: Ok let me see if I understand. weight = [autoreleased] does not retain the value, it is just a pointer to the autoreleased object; doing self.weight = [autoreleased] implies a retain so that I don't lose the object? Oh by the way it worked, thank you.

Comment: @gamda, that's correct. If you declare a property with `retain` or `strong`, saying `self.var = something` is translated to `[self setVar:something]`, and that setter takes care of releasing the old value and retaining the new one. Note that you're still responsible for releasing the property when you're done.